# Symfony2 Assign Entity to User

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Currently three bundles exist, AcmeSecurityBundle, AcmeUserBundle and BloggerBlogBundle.

How do you assign a User Entity to a Blog Entity from a different Bundle? And where saving a Blog Entity how do you auto assign the User.id?

AcmeUserBundle contains a User Entity:

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;
....
}
```

BloggerBlogBundle contains a Blog Entity:

```
class Blog 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", text)
     */
    private $body;
....
}
```

How is the doctrine relationship setup? A User can have many Blogs and a Blog can have one User.

The AcmeSecurityBundle works correctly and allows a User to login, the problem is purely with assigning a User to a Blog.

Comment: Please read the documentation. It has exactly what you want: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: I am already using @ORM\PreUpdate to set Updated Dates on an Entity, but that page does explain how to do a similar thing for saving the current authorised User with an Entity, I imagine this probably has to be set via the Controller, but it still does not explain how to relate Entities from different Bundles.  The only mapping it has is for Entities in the same Bundle via @ORM\ManyToOne etc.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's the same or different bundle at all......You can just do @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyAnotherBundle:MyEntity"....)

Comment: Although that will work it adds a two way dependency between Bundles.  See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24997744/1283381 this means the UserBundle does not depend on the BlogBundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the targetEntity is in a different bundle the correct way to do it is explained here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html

Basically you do not want to introduce a dependency between Bundles.  Instead you need to use a ResolveTargetEntityListener which avoids the need for both Bundles to know about one and other, therefore UserBundle can still be used without the BlogBundle, but BlogBundle requires the UserBundle.

Then when is comes to persisting the User to the DB calling $this->getUser() in a controller will get the currently logged in user, which can then be set to the Blog Entity.